# Failed to authenticate password using codeigniter and gmail

Tags: codeigniter, smtp, gmail

I know this question has been asked before. I have worked through the answers, but I'm still getting a 'Failed to authenticate password. Error: 535-5.7.8' error message.
My code:

```
$config = array(
    'protocol'  => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'mygmail@gmail.com',
    'smtp_pass' => '********',
    'mailtype'  => 'text',
    'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1',
);
$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->from('fromgmail@gmail.com', 'My Name');
$this->email->to('mygmail@gmail.com');
$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing Codeigniter E-mail Library.');
$this->email->send();

echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

This returns the following error message:

```
220 smtp.googlemail.com ESMTP x64sm5635644wrb.10 - gsmtp

hello: 250-smtp.googlemail.com at your service, [89.238.188.204]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8

Failed to authenticate password. Error: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials x64sm5635644wrb.10 - gsmtp
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Thu, 18 May 2017 08:36:24 +0000
From: "My Name" <fromgmail@gmail.com>
Return-Path: <fromgmail@gmail.com>
To: mymail@gmail.com
Subject: =?ISO-8859-1?Q?=41=73=68=20=48=69=6E=69=6E=67=20=46=61=72=6D=20=45=6E=71?= =?ISO-8859-1?Q?=75=69=72=79?=
Reply-To: "fromgmail@gmail.com" <fromgmail@gmail.com>
X-Sender: fromgmail@gmail.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <591d5d088406c@gmail.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0

Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

I have checked the username and password for my google account and know that they are correct.

Comment: You have to set access for less trusted apps in your Gmail account.Are you do this?

Comment: I'm clearly misunderstanding the whole process of sending e-mails via a script. If I'm creating a 'contact us' page for a client, that allows customers to get in touch with them, it's not acceptable for me to ask them for their e-mail account's password. However, this seems to be necessary if I want the script to send an e-mail to a gmail account. What am I missing?

Comment: 1.Login to your gmail account
2.Click on MyAccount from Google Apps
3.Click on 'Signing in to Google' from left panel
4.And Turn on 'Allow less secure apps' from bottom of page

Comment: Click On https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Comment: My was solve by putting $thi->email->set_newline("\r\n");

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Google account

UPDATE: now you need to enable "less secure apps" on your Google Account

https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

You would need to go to your account settings https://www.google.com/settings/security and you would need to enable `Access for less secure apps` which helps to use the google smtp for clients.

May be this will help!!

Answer (score 0):

This is my experience.
Already enabled `less secure apps` on my Google Account and successfully authenticated password using Codeigniter and Gmail. And after a few months of disuse I'm on the CI system again and it seems to fail to authenticate the password, be aware that Google will automatically `disable` this setting when not in use. It's time for you to reactivate it.